# How do I get the text size of a string on a WPF canvas?

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm trying to find the amount of space/width that a string would take when its drawn on a WPF canvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have found an answer to my own question. The [FormattedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx) class seems to have what I'm after.